# How to use configuration maps for custom Quarkus ConfigProperties

Tags: java, properties-file, quarkus, microprofile

For my Quarkus application I'm looking for a way to define a configuration map from within a custom ConfigProperties class. I tried the following:

```java
import io.quarkus.arc.config.ConfigProperties;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigItem;

@ConfigProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
public class MyPropertiesConfiguration { 

    @ConfigItem
    public Map<String, FooConfiguration> foo;

    // ...
}
```

```java
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigGroup;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.ConfigItem;

@ConfigGroup
public class FooConfiguration {

  @ConfigItem
  public String myProperty;
}
```

Given those two classes and the following application.properties file...

```
my-properties.foo.anystring.my-property=bar
```

on startup the application fails with error message:
`javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: No config value of type [java.util.Map] exists for: my-properties.foo`

As far as I understand https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions#configuration-maps the sample should work. What am I doing wrong? Could it happen that this functionality is just limited to Quarkus extensions only?

Answer (score 1):

As written in this [Quarkus github issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8017), this is currently not supported.

My dirty workaround was to use the `ConfigProvider` directly. Use with care.

```java
  public static Map<String, String> getMapFromConfig(String prefix) {
    final Config config = ConfigProvider.getConfig();
    final Iterable<String> propertyNames = config.getPropertyNames();
    return StreamSupport.stream(propertyNames.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(name -> name.startsWith(prefix) && !name.equalsIgnoreCase(prefix))
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                propertyName -> cleanupPropertyName(propertyName.substring(prefix.length() + 1)),
                propertyName -> config.getOptionalValue(propertyName, String.class).orElse("")));
  }

  /** Remove start and end double quotes */
  public static String cleanupPropertyName(String name) {
    if (name.startsWith("\"") && name.endsWith("\"")) {
      return name.substring(1, name.length() - 1);
    }
    return name;
  }
```

My config looks like this:

```yaml
property-templates:
  "my.key": value 1
  "my.second.key": value 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Declare the configuration like this

```
import io.quarkus.arc.config.ConfigProperties;

@ConfigProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class AppSpecificConfig {

    public String property;

}
```

The `application.properties` file will contain

```
myapp.property=foo
```

And then you can `@Inject` an instance of this class anywhere within your application.

For more details, see https://quarkus.io/guides/config#using-configproperties

Comment: Hi @Jan Martiška, thx for your reply. The definition and injection of simple properties is clear. I'm looking for a way to setup a named configuration using a java.util.Map. In the sample I provided in my question I try to tell quarkus to put a new `FooConfiguration` item with `myProperty = bar` onto the map `foo` using string `anystring` as key.

Comment: Ah, then I think no, that facility is currently only for extensions. There is an alternative, if you really want to inject maps, you can create a `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.Converter<Map>`, but that one will only be able to map one configuration property into a `Map` object, meaning the property will have to contain all keys and values in a particular parseable format.

Comment: @JanMartiška do you have an example how to create and register such converter for Map?

Comment: @stinger Try following the guide at https://quarkus.io/guides/config#custom-configuration-converters except that you will use a `Map<String, String>` instead of `MicroProfileCustomValue`

Answer (score -2):

```java
@ConfigProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
public class MyPropertiesConfiguration { 

    Map<String, FooConfiguration> foo;

    interface FooConfgiruation {
       // props go here
       String property1();
    }
}
```

And you're good to go.

And check the official documentation for more info:

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings#maps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)